# How to avoid Image position change in TSpeedButton when caption changes?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need to arrange all buttons icons on same alignment. But **as the caption length changes button image position changes**... Please suggest me the way to avoid it. I am using **TSpeedButton**.

[image: TSpeedButton with different captions]

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that by editing `Margin` property of `TSpeedButton`. That way all the glyphs will be aligned to `Layout` and offset by `Margin` value.

Comment: +1. I almost answered this, but couldn't remember whether Margin existed in D7. By the time I got around to starting the VM where D7 is installed to check, you'd gotten here first. :)

Comment: LOLs, I just was working in D7 and tested it in new Application :)